# Prepare failed 0x1 Android

Tags: android

I have a wvm file I'm trying to load, but it always fail on prepare with IO exception.

If I'm trying to run the same url in VLC player on the same device it will play normally.

This is my MediaPlayer code

```
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(file_url));

    if(mPlayer != null){
        mPlayer.setSurface(s);
        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        video_prepared = true;
        if(got_initial_media_hit) {
            OnEvent(PLAYER_EVENT.load);
        }
    }
    else {
        OnError(PLAYER_ERRORS.player_not_loaded, "");
    }
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
09-29 14:48:56.314: E/MediaPlayer(18209): error (1, -1)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209): create failed:
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:792)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:769)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at com.tvinci.sdk.player.DefaultPlayer.initPlayer(DefaultPlayer.java:247)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at com.tvinci.sdk.player.DefaultPlayer.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(DefaultPlayer.java:287)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer(TextureView.java:385)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12804)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12833)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12833)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12833)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13657)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13947)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2224)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12838)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12880)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1411)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1359)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2367)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2239)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1872)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-29 14:48:56.334: D/MediaPlayer(18209):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What can it be? 
Thanks

Edit:

If I'm using VideoView instead it works like a charm. Any ideas?

Comment: which line is 247 of DefaultPlayer.java?

Comment: @MikeIsrael it's `mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(file_url));` This error happens if you have too many MediaPlayers open, or if the codec of the video/audio is not supported (or permission errors)

Answer (score 1):

I encounter several issues regarding this Create function.

First one, it seems like Java must know the type of the file so you must write "file://" at the beginning of your file path. See [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15444165/62921).

Then, later on, I was appending my file path with the `FilesDir.AbsolutePath` and I was missing a "/" between them.

So this error is really related to the Create function and not what's come after. So have a look to your very first line. Good luck.